# Class encapsulating $_SESSION - problem

Tags: php, session-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Class encapsulating $_SESSION - problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696584/class-encapsulating-session-problem)

include/session.php:

```
/*
    Use the static method getInstance to get the object.
*/

class Session
{
    const SESSION_STARTED = TRUE;
    const SESSION_NOT_STARTED = FALSE;

    // The state of the session
    private $sessionState = self::SESSION_NOT_STARTED;

    // THE only instance of the class
    private static $instance;

    protected function __construct() { }

    public function __destruct() {
      session_write_close();
    }


    /**
    *    Returns THE instance of 'Session'.
    *    The session is automatically initialized if it wasn't.
    *    
    *    @return    object
    **/

    public static function GetInstance()
    {
        if ( !isset(self::$instance))
        {
            self::$instance = new self;
        }

        self::$instance->startSession();

        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function getID() {
      return session_id();
    }


    /**
    *    (Re)starts the session.
    *    
    *    @return    bool    TRUE if the session has been initialized, else FALSE.
    **/

    public function startSession()
    {
        if ( $this->sessionState == self::SESSION_NOT_STARTED )
        {
            $this->sessionState = session_start();
        }

        return $this->sessionState;
    }


    /**
     *    Creates a new session.
     **/         
    public function newSession() {
        return session_regenerate_id(true);
    }


    /**
    *    Stores datas in the session.
    *    Example: $instance->foo = 'bar';
    *    
    *    @param    name    Name of the datas.
    *    @param    value    Your datas.
    *    @return    void
    **/

    public function __set( $name , $value )
    {
        $_SESSION[$name] = $value;
    }


    /**
    *    Gets datas from the session.
    *    Example: echo $instance->foo;
    *    
    *    @param    name    Name of the datas to get.
    *    @return    mixed    Datas stored in session.
    **/

    public function __get( $name )
    {
        if ( isset($_SESSION[$name]))
        {
            $ret = $_SESSION[$name];
            return $ret;
        }
    }


    public function __isset( $name )
    {
        return isset($_SESSION[$name]);
    }


    public function __unset( $name )
    {
        unset( $_SESSION[$name] );
    }


    /**
    *    Destroys the current session.
    *    
    *    @return    bool    TRUE is session has been deleted, else FALSE.
    **/

    public function destroy()
    {    
      session_start();
      session_unset();
      session_destroy();
    }
}

?>
```

test.php:

```
<?php

require_once('include/session.php');

$session = Session::GetInstance();
$session->foo = 'bar';
$session->baz = array();
$session->baz['foo'] = 'bar';
$session->baz['derp'] = array();
$session->baz['derp']['php_sucks'] = 'this will never work';

var_dump($session->foo); echo '<br>';
var_dump($session->baz); echo '<br>';
var_dump($session->baz['foo']); echo '<br>';
var_dump($session->baz['derp']); echo '<br>';
var_dump($session->baz['derp']['php_sucks']); echo '<br>';


?>
```

output:

```
string(3) "bar" 
array(0) { } 
NULL 
NULL 
NULL
```

Why isn't the $session->baz array being filled?

Comment: -1 for gratuitous singletons -- as well as for wrapping $_SESSION with a class that provides no useful functionality.

Comment: @Andre it's not there, that's what the `__set` and `__get` methods are for.

Comment: @cHao, it may be gratuitous, but it IS useful, because there are plenty of times where you need to use a session variable, but aren't sure if you've (yet) called `session_start`. By using a singleton, you don't have to worry about calling it more than once.

Comment: The alternative solution is to *know what your program is doing*. Besides, i don't see a check for whether the session's been started before returning stuff from `__get`.  So you've just added semi-required-but-you-can-get-away-with-forgetting calls to `Session::GetInstance` (which could just as easily be forgotten, and would only "work" due to it being called one of the other 50 million places session variables were used.  A little refactoring, a little forgetting to start the session, and suddenly one day an edit halfway across the app breaks sessions.

Comment: Andre, baz is a session variable...look at Session's overriden magic methods; $this->baz is supposed to set $_SESSION['baz'].  cHao...you're a moron, I don't want there to exist the possibility of two instances trying to separately manage the session at the same time, and I wasn't asking for worthless and pedantic comments about basic design patterns anyway.

Comment: @cHao: lolwut?  The whole point is to use this object for all session interactions.  So do tell me how I'd forget to call Session::GetInstance(), if Session is always what I'd use anyway in the "other 50 million places".

Comment: @Jason: It doesn't matter what you were asking for.  If i think it's a bad idea, i'll say so.  Better you hear about it now than after you've written 100k lines of code that depends on it.  And frankly, this is a bad idea -- you should already know when sessions are started and when they aren't.  Either way, PHP makes singletons unnecessary.  Statics can be called non-statically, meaning you can have 50 million `Session`s without any issues.  Or you can just call `Session::start()` if you want.

Comment: @Jason: If you're the only one ever adding code to your app, good for you.  If there will be anyone else, that's one more thing somebody can forget -- and they'll almost always be able to get away with it.

Comment: cHao: I am far from being adept in PHP...but I do know that you are just plain wrong about Singletons not being needed in PHP.  In fact everything you said is flat-out terrible and incorrect.  Yes, you can call GetInstance() non-statically, so what, it won't create any more instances, seeing that this function is contingent on the *static* class member, Session::$instance.  btw, did you know that "classes which provide no useful functionality" can be inherited by more useful classes?

Comment: @Jason: What i'm saying is that in PHP, if all your methods and fields are static, you have all the benefits of a singleton -- *including* the ability to pass a `Session` around at will, if that's your thing -- without the need to care whether you have 1, 2, 2342324, or *zero* instances.  They'll all modify the same (static) data, and all act like the same instance.  Meaning, frankly, there *is.  no.  use.  for.  Singletons.  in.  PHP.*  That you don't understand that doesn't make me wrong.

Comment: @cHao: What if all my methods and fields *aren't* static?

Comment: @Jason: Then you either insist on ignoring the point, or have data that's designed to be unique per instance -- and thus, by definition, are designing the class to have multiple instances (ie: *it shouldn't be a singleton*).

Comment: @Jason: As for the inheritance thing...PHP is dynamically typed.  Just about every line of OO PHP code i've ever seen uses duck typing, and doesn't care about the actual type.  Meaning that inheritance in PHP is more about avoiding duplication of code than creating a hierarchy, and if there's no useful functionality, there's nothing worth inheriting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call $session->baz['foo'], $session->baz returns a copy of the array that is in the session and then you add the 'foo' element to it. This copy is not the copy inside your class and is pretty much instantly discarded.

You'll need to change the way you handle having arrays in there, ie using some getters and setters (including the magic ones) or look into ways of getting the 'baz' element out by reference instead of copy.